# Installing Istio on WSL2 fails with "FailedMount" for pods

Tags: kubernetes, istio, wsl-2, kind

I have set up a local kubernetes cluster using [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io) on WSL2 (Ubuntu distro). I managed to create a cluster successfully. Then I try to install istio using helm following the [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/helm/).

Everything looks fine till I check the status of istio pods using `kubectl get pods -n istio-system` for which I get the response

```
istio-egressgateway-645df98b64-tml4k    0/1     ContainerCreating   0          39m
istio-ingressgateway-6c7f679666-lxj8r   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          39m
istiod-657558ff59-fhpgl                 0/1     ContainerCreating   0          39m
```

The pods continue to stay in `ContainerCreating` status. So, I checked the pod using `kubectl describe pod -n istio-system istio-egressgateway-645df98b64-tml4k` and I see the following events with warnings:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    27m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned istio-system/istio-egressgateway-645df98b64-tml4k to msg-local-worker2
  Warning  FailedMount  25m                   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istio-token istiod-ca-cert], unattached volumes=[istio-token podinfo istio-envoy istio-data egressgateway-ca-certs config-volume egressgateway-certs istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-2k6nv istiod-ca-cert]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  22m                   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istio-token istiod-ca-cert], unattached volumes=[istio-token istio-envoy istiod-ca-cert config-volume istio-data podinfo egressgateway-certs egressgateway-ca-certs istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-2k6nv]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  20m (x11 over 27m)    kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istio-token" : failed to fetch token: the API server does not have TokenRequest endpoints enabled
  Warning  FailedMount  20m                   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istiod-ca-cert istio-token], unattached volumes=[istio-envoy podinfo istiod-ca-cert istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-2k6nv istio-token config-volume egressgateway-certs istio-data egressgateway-ca-certs]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  11m                   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istiod-ca-cert istio-token], unattached volumes=[podinfo istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-2k6nv istio-envoy config-volume istio-data istiod-ca-cert egressgateway-certs egressgateway-ca-certs istio-token]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  7m2s (x3 over 9m16s)  kubelet            (combined from similar events): Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[istio-token istiod-ca-cert], unattached volumes=[egressgateway-certs istio-envoy istio-token egressgateway-ca-certs istio-egressgateway-service-account-token-2k6nv istio-data istiod-ca-cert config-volume podinfo]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  38s (x18 over 27m)    kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "istiod-ca-cert" : configmap "istio-ca-root-cert" not found
```

Comment: Could you try to restart the `istiod` Pod and share the results?

Comment: there is a strange log; about TokenRequest not being enabled on the api server. can you paste the yaml used to start the api server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed to figure out the problem thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959). I needed to enable [service account token volume projection](https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests/issues/959).

The exact solution is found [here](https://github.com/linkerd/linkerd2/issues/3260). I changed my cluster configuration (kind-config.yaml) to

```
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.sigs.k8s.io/v1alpha4
kubeadmConfigPatches:
  - |
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
    kind: ClusterConfiguration
    metadata:
      name: config
    apiServer:
      extraArgs:
        "service-account-issuer": "kubernetes.default.svc"
        "service-account-signing-key-file": "/etc/kubernetes/pki/sa.key"
nodes:
  - role: control-plane
  - role: worker
  - role: worker
```

Then started the cluster using `kind create cluster --name my-cluster --config ./kind-config.yaml`. I installed istio normally on this cluster and the pods are running now.

Answer (score 0):

Validates that the configuration pods in the kube-system namespace are running.

$>: kubectl -n kube-system get all

In my case there were pods with ImagePullBackOff errors, I solved the problem with the images for and with the pods running correctly I was able to install istio correctly.

$>: k -n istio-system get all

[namespace istio-system, all runnning resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKBCX.png)

minikube version: v1.31.0
commit: 47aea544e09f11f475f33e8d126f9eb15e34a4c0